# ASP.Net EF not updating relationships

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4, entity-relationship, object-persistence

I've got a table which contains a bunch of assets that are organized into multiple hierarchies such that the table has a many-to-many relationship with itself (each asset can have multiple children AND multiple parents).  I'm using the following code to reassign a child asset's parents. I realize the code seems redundant; before I was simply using the child object to make the change in relationship, but to be thorough, I decided to try changing the relationship from both the child and the parent object.

```
int NewParentID = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
Asset NewParent = DataContext.Assets.Where(asset => asset.AssetID == NewParentID).First();
Asset Child = DataContext.Assets.Where(asset => asset.AssetID == AssetID).First();
IEnumerable<Asset> OldParents = Child.ParentAssets.Where(asset => asset.AssetType == Child.OrganizationalParentAssetType);
foreach (Asset a in OldParents)
{
    a.ChildAssets.Remove(Child);
    Child.ParentAssets.Remove(a);
}
Child.ParentAssets.Add(NewParent);
NewParent.ChildAssets.Add(Child);
DataContext.SaveChanges();
```

Can anyone think of a reason why DataContext.SaveChanges() would not persist the relationship changes being made in this code?  Changing simple property values works just fine (e.g. Child.AssetName = "Whatever", is persisted to the database, no problems).

Any help is much appreciated!

Regards,

Trevor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake.  I had LazyLoading enabled.